# how annotate foreign key in entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

historically, I need the following data model:

```
public class Banner
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    ???
    public int IdForResult { get; set; }
    ???
    public BannerResult Result { get; set; }
}

public class BannerResult
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    ???
    public int IdForBanner { get; set; }
    ???
    public Banner Banner { get; set; }
}
```

how should i annotate it in entity framework?

Answer (score 1):

When configuring foreign keys e.g, one-to-one relationships, Entity Framework requires that the primary key of the dependent also be the foreign key.

Sample code

```
[Table("Accounts")]
public class DbAccount
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Account")]
    public virtual DbLicense License { get; set; }
}

[Table("Licenses")]
public class DbLicense
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Account")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("License")]
    public virtual DbAccount Account { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: what means ForeignKey("Account"), maybe it needed on AccountId ?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Banner
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int IdForResult { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("IdForResult")]
    public BannerResult Result { get; set; }
}

public class BannerResult
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int IdForBanner { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("IdForBanner")]
    public Banner Banner { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'Models.BannersResult' and 'Models.Banner'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.